# Performance hit of installing a new hard drive in a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, upgrade, hardware-recommendation

I have a MacBook Pro 5,3 with a 7200 rpm 500 GB hard drive. I am running out of space and I have been considering upgrading with Western Digital's 1 TB laptop hard drive. I am just curious if I am going to get a big hit to my performance.

This is the hard drive I am looking at:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136545

Answer (score 2):

**ATTENTION**

You do not specify a MacBook pro, but mine (pre-unibody) it ca not take those drives as you can read it has **12.5mm height** and the **maximum of a MBP Drive is 9.5mm**

That is why several 500Gb drives did not fit MBP's and the one you are mentioning will never fit your laptop.

---

**added**

Currently, the max capacity on a 9.5mm Hard Drive is 750Gb ([WD Scorpio Blue 5400rpm](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Western%20Digital/WD7500BPVT/)), and SSD is 480Gb ([OWC SSD Extreme Pro](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/SSDMX480/)) --> I bought mine here but 240Gb, it's superb!

to learn how to swap them (unibody, late 2008 models), see this [OWC video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3Ve01UFuSA) and if you want to check the performance from an SSD and a HHD, [please check this video](http://eshop.macsales.com/Video/SSD/Performance_Test).

[my own SSD](http://flic.kr/p/8xdnM8):

[image]

Comment: Well, he did say 5,3 in his MBP model, which I believe is unibody.

Comment: (no idea what 5.3 represents, sorry) but it is still 9,5mm :)

Answer (score 0):

If the new drive is also 7200 rpm, what you’re going to get is usually a faster drive, more modern with (possibly) more internal cache which could lead to a slight improvement. In any case, the difference between 7200 and 5400 rpm is not *that much*. There is a difference and you will notice it in certain things, but there are other factors that will affect performance way before the disk in a day to day usage. Unless all you do is write/read files from the disk, get the bigger disk you can afford. Of course you can always get a 2TB external FW drive and store all the junk there, while still having plenty of room in the internal drive.

Or you could get a smaller 128/256 SSD super faster drive and store *most* of your stuff in your external 500rpm drive (in a USB External Enclosure for 10 bucks), but leaving your OS in the internal super fast SSD.

Options… options… :)

In any case, always get as much ram as you can afford.

Comment: I would like an internal 1 tb hard drive because I triple boot my laptop and I want to give my other OSs more space

Comment: this is the western digital hard drive: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136545

Comment: Yes I see the disk. The seek time of a of a 7200 RPM disk is faster and there will be slight differences, however there are a few small disadvantages of using a 7200 RPM disk: it uses more power, usually makes more noise and it generates more heat. If you value space, then go ahead and purchase the biggest drive you can afford :) There are 7200 RPM 1B drives too if that worries you.